# How to properly debug Spring Events?

Tags: java, spring, event-handling

i'm starting to use Spring Events (using custom events and `@EventListener` annotation).
One of my co-worker asked me if it wouldn't be good to add a log line in the `@EventListener` method.
So i started to look if there were any "good practices" to debugging Spring Event instead of adding log lines everywhere.
Kind of a generic way to know which and when events were send and which listener treated them.

Put in simple terms: How to properly trace and debug Spring Event usages ?

Could not find any blog, article or StackOverflow discussion on the subject. Could someone point me in the right direction ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried using your IDE debugger with break points?

Answer (score 1):

- You can create another logging event listener that listens for the events you specify and logs.

```
  @Component
  public class LoggingEventListener {
  
    @EventListener(classes=...)
    public void logEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        ...
    }
  }
```

- Or you can write log `aspect` based on the `@EventListener` annotation and it logs it.

Comment: Thank's for your time!
I thought about your first point but i was hopping for something else. However your second point on `aspect` based on the `@EventListener` is interesting. I will dig into it.